A movie about a woman kidnapped with a candy bar
In the beginning of the movie, the protagonist/antagonist definitely kidnapped a woman by pointing a candy bar at her back. She thinks it's a gun. Then both of them ride a car and are chased by police.
Another scene that I recall is a police officer vomits on the windshield of the police car.
It's from 1990's to 2000's. A Hollywood movie. In English language. Its genre is action. Probably thriller too. Too bad I can't remember the actor. The kidnapper is just like a typical tough guy. The woman's car was maybe red.

I believe you're looking for the movie The Chase 1994 starring Charlie Sheen.
At the beginning of the movie Sheen comes across two police officers and a young lady. After events unfold he panics and kidnaps the woman using only a candy bar.
Here is the trailer:




Yup. She also vomits on a police car.

thank you. So, it's the girl who vomit. Not the police
